# How to execute an Informix ISQL query with a join

Tags: join, informix

I have a table that already has values in it. The value I want to update is `g_fuel_prft.billed_qty`. I need to multiple a number from this table times a number from another table to get the value.

So table names are `inv_header` which contains `inv_header.rpt_factor` and `g_fuel_prft` which contains `g_fuel_prft.billed_qty`. The criteria is `where inv_header.link=g_fuel_prft.lnk AND inv_header.rpt_factor = 0`.

once I have those rows selected I want to update them to `billed_qty * rpt_factor`

```
update g_fuel_prft
set billed_qty = (inv_header.rpt_factor * g_fuel_prft.billed_qty)
         where exists
                 (select billed_qty,ivh_rpt_factor from g_fuel_prft,inv_header
                 where g_fuel_prft.prodlnk = inv_header.ivh_link
                 and inv_header.ivh_rpt_factor = 0)
```

I am getting an 201 syntax error

Comment: Can you try using this subquery instead `(select 1 from inv_header a where g_fuel_prft.prodlnk = a.ivh_link and ivh_rpt_factor = 0)`?

Comment: Please add an outline schema and relevant data for each of the tables.  Without that, there can only be limited testing of the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to `inv_header.rpt_factor` like that.  You'll need to place it into a sub-query.

```
UPDATE g_fuel_prft
   SET billed_qty = ((SELECT inv_header.rpt_factor
                        FROM inv_header
                       WHERE g_fuel_prft.prodlnk = inv_header.ivh_link) *
                     g_fuel_prft.billed_qty)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM g_fuel_prft
                 JOIN inv_header ON g_fuel_prft.prodlnk = inv_header.ivh_link
                WHERE inv_header.ivh_rpt_factor = 0)
```

With an EXISTS query, the select-list doesn't matter and `*` is conventional.  You might need more restrictions in the sub-select within the SET clause.  It depends on what sort of relationship there is between the joining columns (1:1, 1:N, N:1, M:N).

Given the minimal schema below, the query above is syntactically valid. It's hard to test it without valid sample data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS g_fuel_prft;
CREATE TABLE g_fuel_prft
(
    prodlnk         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    billed_qty      DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inv_header;
CREATE TABLE inv_header
(
    rpt_factor      DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL,
    ivh_link        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ivh_rpt_factor  DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL
);
```